# Permissions in SharePoint between Libraries

Tags: workflow

We have a site that contains all of our Training Material. It is read-only to everyone except the training department.

The Business is responsible for sending us changes through the mail. We thought it would be better if they could move or copy to our dropoff rather than download and upload.

**The problem we have run into is** that in order for them to move or copy from the Production library they need more than “read” access. Can you think of any other way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on approval in the library, and make the other users contributors. This way, they'd be able to edit files, but no one would be able to see any of their changes until the changes were approved by someone in the training dept. This could also make document editing go smoother, as the business users could directly edit the files in place, instead of dealing with the inevitable versioning issues that arise from emailing docs back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom permission level that gives them read and add permissions. Apply this to your library and they can add the new content as it becomes available, but can't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new custom permission level with only view and add by following the mentioned steps below :

- Site settings > Site permissions.
- from the above ribbon select Permissions Levels.
- Click add permission level.
- Below List permissions > select Add Item, View Items